# Cannot change MySQL root password

Tags: mysql, password

I have run the following commands found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html).

```
shell> mysql
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass'
```

But when I go to login as root, I can type any string as a password, and it will still let me login.

How can I enforce a password for root, and not allow anonymous users by simply typing `mysql`

Comment: Do you have authentication methods other than password enabled for root?

Comment: I am not sure. Just installed MySQL on a virtual machine. I'm not sure how to enable authentication methods with this DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

I ran through the command line wizard to set this up:
`shell> mysql_secure_installation`

Then entered the following:
`shell> mysql`
`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED with mysql_native_password;`
`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

Credit goes to this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35264497/mysql-5-7-11-mysql-secure-installation-dont-work).

Answer (score -3):

You wanna try this granting all users by password

```
Grant All Privileges ON *.* to 'USER_NAME'@'%' Identified By 'YOUR_PASSWORD'; 

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Invalid syntax in MySQL-8.0. Also `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` isn't required. `wanna` isn't a word.